# Extra Single Quotes in Prepared Statement with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to use JDBC to insert some records to a MySQL database. While trying to insert dynamic values to my prepared statement it seems I'm getting extra single quotes added. I'm not entirely sure if that's my problem but IntelliJ is giving me the following error which leads me to believe the single quotes are the problem.

Error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20221105T145913034789400' (username, message) VALUES ('fake username','test record')' at line 1
```

My ConnectionHandler class calls addToTable() in my Server class which is where the error comes from.

ConnectionHandler Class

```
server.addToTable("fake username", "test message");
```

Server Class

```
    public void addToTable(String sUser, String sMessage) {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...", "myusername...", "mypassword...");
        String sPreStatement = "INSERT INTO ? (username, message) VALUES (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement SQLstatement = conn.prepareStatement(sPreStatement);
        SQLstatement.setString(1, sTable);
        SQLstatement.setString(2, sUser);
        SQLstatement.setString(3, sMessage);
        SQLstatement.execute();
        SQLstatement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The table is a randomly generated table, which is created in the Server objects constructor. In this case its 20221105T145913034789400. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `INSERT INTO ?` ← You should not do that.  A table name is not a value, it’s an identifier.  Just use `"INSERT INTO " + sTable + " (username, message) VALUES (?,?)"`.  I assume the table name does not come from user input, so the risk of SQL injection is low to nonexistent.  (Side note:  don’t start every string variable with `s`.  That’s Hungarian notation, which was thoroughly discredited and reviled a long time ago as a bad programming practice.)

Comment: Object name cannot be inserted into the query as literal value. In some frameworks it is possible by using special placeholder.. test `.. sPreStatement = "INSERT INTO ?? (username, message) VALUES (?,?)"; ..` or read the reference malual - maybe your framework have some another placeholder for object name... or needs in the method other than `setString`.. or have no such feature at all.